# paycheck tax withholding ?

Tags: united-states, taxes, paycheck

I received my first paycheck  and 200 in taxes were taken out but I never received a w-4 or i9 
Which is what I am used to were I can claim 0 5.
So how can these taxes be taken out if I never received those forms of any kind

Comment: May be some default values used instead...Until you fill out the form itself and pass it to the employer

Answer (score 7):

The IRS instructions cover this situation.  In the absence of a valid completed W-4, an employer must withhold at the highest rate - single with 0 allowances.  This is covered in the first paragraph of the following document:

[Topic 753 - Form W-4 – Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc753.html)

> If an employee fails to give you a properly completed Form W-4, you must withhold federal income taxes from his or her wages as if he or she were single and claiming no withholding allowances.

The I-9 should have no effect on your tax withholding, since it only certifies that you have the **right** to work in the United States, not that you have any specific tax condition.

A new W-4 can be filed at any time.  The above document specifies the maximum amount of time before the new document must be accepted.

If you are certain you have not been given a W-4 or I-9 to complete, you may wish to inquire further of your employer, and save those pay stubs.  Without proper documentation, your employer may act shadily and may not be making proper payments to the IRS on your behalf or his own.

Comment: Looks like I beat you to it by 2 minutes. But your answer is a little more thorough so I merged in the quote into your answer and deleted mine.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I asked if I could get a w4 and he said "he dosnt subcontract insurance". This was in a text

Comment: What kinda scam could he be doing by not giving me the forms to fill out like i9 or w2.

Comment: Ok I see . Thank you again I will find out. I wonder what will happen if he refuses to give me these forms

Comment: @JD You may want to consider reporting your employer to the IRS if you have proof that they are not providing all required tax forms.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is any scamming going on - probably they are just slow with the forms, or they offer it on the internal website and the OP didn't realize it yet. Either way, the amount of taxes owed is independent of W-4 anyway; it just defines the _pre-payments_, OP will get back any overpayments.